# how to get exact user name from get-mobiledevicestatistics in powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I have a small script to get all user mobile devices info from exchange 2013 server.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
ForEach {Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$_.Identity} |
Select-Object @{label="User" ; expression={$_.Identity}},DeviceOS, lastsuccesssync
```

I just want to get an exact user name instead of a path in AD. How can I do it in `expression={?}`

Here is another script to do it, it gives me the user name, but all devices belongs to user are not in separated lines, they all in one line...

```
$EASMailboxes = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"} | Get-Mailbox
$EASMailboxes | Select-Object DisplayName, PrimarySMTPAddress, @{Name="Mobile Devices";Expression={(Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.Identity).DeviceOS}} | 
Out-GridView
```

Comment: What does the username currently look like? Can you update the question with that?

Comment: it looks like this `domain.com/Users/OU/UserName/ExchangeActiveSyncDevices/iPhone`. So I am using this `expression={$_.Identity -split "/" | select -last -3}` to get the name , but it gives me all last 3 words...I just need the 3rd from last

Comment: In that one case it would not be an issue but are all usernames in that same ou? You could get it from the `Get-Mailbox` as you already know it.

Comment: @Matt, Yes, you are right , that will be another issue. I updated another script, this one gives me the user name but all devices belongs to the user will be in one line, I would have each device in seperated lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the environment to test this but is this not what you are looking for ?

```powershell
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach {
    $user = $_.SamAccountName
    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$_.Identity |
    Select-Object @{label="User" ; expression={$user}},DeviceOS, lastsuccesssync
}
```

That should output the user for every device they own on its own line. You could then easily export this to `Export-CSV` or some such thing that way.

We save the `$user` so it is available later in the pipe. Could also have used `Add-Member` but the result would have been the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the identity field, which looks like this

```
domain.com/Users/OU/UserName/ExchangeActiveSyncDevices/iPhone
```

Then to split on the `/` and get the third result, you simply request:

```
$_.Identity.Split("/")[3]

>UserName
```

PowerShell begins indexing with number zero, so to request the fourth entry in the list, we request index number 3.

**Update**

OP mentioned that the OU level might vary, meaning that he couldn't count on a fixed position to request the Index.  In order to accomodte that scenario, try this method, which will look for the index of ExchangeActiveSyncDevices and then pick the index position before that.

```
$_.Identity.Split('/')[($_.Identity.Split('/').Indexof('ExchangeActiveSyncDevices')-1)]
```

Comment: like @matt pointed out, I can't use [#] cus the OU level is uncertain.

Comment: Added a different method, based on looking for the index position before ExchangeActiveSynDevices.

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited|foreach {Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$_.identity} |Select-Object @{l="user";e={$_.Identity.parent.parent.name}}, lastsuccesssync
on e2k13
```