# How do I get my username for Exchange with PowerShell

Tags: exchangewebservices, powershell-3.0

Is there any command, or other way, that I can get the username that I have used for logging in to the Exchange-module in PowerShell?

For clarification:
This functionality is to be used in a script that will handle permissions for a group of Exchange-admins. And to avoid having to type their admin-accountnames each time they run the script, it would be great if the script could get the name of the account they used when logging in with the PowerShell Exchange-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an clear answer for this, so I insteed used my domain-AD username to search for correct useraccount.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your username in the following code:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach {
    $user = $_.SamAccountName
    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$_.Identity |
    Select-Object @{label="User" ; expression={$user}},DeviceOS, lastsuccesssync
}
```

[how to get exact user name from get-mobiledevicestatistics in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475711/how-to-get-exact-user-name-from-get-mobiledevicestatistics-in-powershell)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, but since we have a huge number of users, get them all is not an option.
Plus, testing the code gives a list of evert user, their device (if they have any) and last successful sync.

Comment: you can try the following code : "Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Format-Table -Auto DisplayName, LitigationHoldEnabled"
reference from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/use-powershell-to-display-mailbox-information